# I don't know how to replace a line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I don't now know how to do it

It's simple, I even made a short video https://youtu.be/3-fHpqXdK8c

Comment: Ask your question here, don't just drop a link to YT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can replace text in Notepad++ and many other apps by using "Regular Expressions". (Research and study "regular expressions" if necessary.) In Notepad++, type Ctrl-Shift-F, which launches "find in files", click the "Regular Expressions" radio button in the lower-left quarter, then enter a regular expression and a replacement string. For example:

Regular expression string: `^ReplacedBlocks: (.*)$`

Replacement string: `ReversedClocks: $1`

That would change THIS: 
`ReplacedBlocks: (AIR,LAVA,1,2)`

into THIS: 
`ReversedClocks: (AIR,LAVA,1,2)`

Comment: um i do have discord if that may help so i can tell you.

Comment: https://discord.gg/TAuuVmv

Comment: why is my question being down voted. i need help

Comment: https://youtu.be/3-fHpqXdK8c

Comment: @SpeedRider because your question is entirely in videos and will become invalid when the video is removed. Questions must be self-contained. See [Video Questions and Answers](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13072/241386)